# The Nav bar is positioned as fixed. The image below it moves to the upper right of nav bar overlapping it. The image should remain at the bottom

Tags: html, css

[Image overlaps Flex Navbar](https://roberla.github.io/Foods/)[Image overlap NavBar]I have a Navbar that is fixed and a Flexbox. The image below called prestige appears to the right side overlapping the Navbar. The image needs to remain at the bottom of the page.

```
<div class="nav">
  <img class="logo" src="images/food.png" alt="Food">
   <div class="link"><a href="index.html">Home</a><div class="link">
   <div class="link"><a href="pages/gallery.html">Gallery</a><div class="link">
<div class="link"><a href="pages/services.html">Services</a><div class="link">
<div class="link"><a href="pages/contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a><div class="link">
    </div>

<img class="cover" src="images/prestige.jpeg" alt="Prestige Food">
```

Need the prestige image to NOT overlap on top of Flexbox Navbar but expand the entire width of the page at the bottom.

```
 .nav {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.1%;
  z-index: 3;
}

 .link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
 }
 .nav a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
 }

.cover {
 grid-column: 1 / 7;
 grid-row: 3 / 5;
 }`
```

Comment: pls show your code snippet

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is still missing the CSS needed to help debug your issue. Please [edit] your question to include enough code to reproduce your problem. (There are also image placeholders you can use so you don't have broken images in your example code like https://picsum.photos/ and https://placeholder.com/)

Comment: Hello, I would really appreciate some help. I have included a screen print of the problem.